# Merging parent and lazy child collection list

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, merge

1 parent entity may have 0 or multiple lazy child entities

For example, there is a function changing the status column in parent and child entities, while merge(parent), parent entity is updated but child entities are insert new instead of update.

Both the child entities id, data are exactly the same as in database while debugging.

The parent object is put in @SessionAttributes in spring controller, would it be the reason?

Even I merge only the child list, merge(childList), it create new records instead of update also.

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "member")
    public class Member implements Serializable{



        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name="id")
        private int id;

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "memberParent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        public List<Child> ChildList


        getter setter......

    }

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "child")
    public class Child implements Serializable{



        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name="id")
        private int id;

    @Column(name="member_id")
        private int mem_id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "member_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
        })
        public Member memberParent;


        getter setter......

    }




//Controller
    @SessionAttributes({"member"})
    public class Appcontroller {

    @Transactional
        @RequestMapping(value = {"/update-member/{id}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String viewEditRepresetative(ModelMap model, @PathVariable ind id) {
        Member member = memberService.find(id);
        model.addAttributes("member", member);

    }

    @Transactional
        @RequestMapping(value = {"/update-member"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String viewEditRepresetative(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest reques, @Valid @ModelAttribute("member") Member member, BindingResult result,
                RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, SessionStatus status) {
        if (!result.hasErrors()) {
            memberService.merge(member);
        }

    }
```

Comment: put your code as well, so it will be helpful to understand how you tried and what is the exact problem

Comment: @JekinKalariya Hi I just updated with code

Comment: http://www.programmingforfuture.com/2011/02/hibernate-merge-may-insert-new-record.html might help you

Comment: I tried the solution but not successful, but I found that the Id is already there before I set

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any **parent child relationship** in your snapshot code.

Please amend the code for child class with below code to create the inheritance relationship.

```
public class Child extends Member implements Serializable{
```

Extending the Child class to the Parent(Member) will reflect the required changes related to lazy loading.